# Lubuntu 22.04.1 New Install Sticks at Update and then crashes

Tags: boot, kernel, lubuntu

I have a new install on a Dell Insperion N4110 Corei3.  I can load to hard drive and run.  However, when it goes to update (303 apps) it sticks at 86% waiting for something.  I can force a stop but when I reboot and go to Ubuntu the system crashes.  The final error is end Kernal panic - not syncing: VFS Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)  }---
I have repeated by reloading several times with same result.  Is there a way to recover and survive an update?

Comment: You mention it stopping at 86%, how did you perform the update?  Was it at GUI, or terminal (I prefer terminal, especially if there are problems as the progress messages and clues are provided on your terminal instead of needing to hunt for them in logs). You mention force stop? but not how?  Was it a *clean* `kill`, a SysRq command etc? then kernel panic post reboot (*which reads like you did an unclean stop & thus kernel panic was due to unclean shutdown & user procedural issue.. Did you `fsck` the disk & then boot?*)  Please clarify with specifics.

Comment: The update was with Muon Package Manager.  I forced a hard stop with the power button, so yes an unclean shutdown.  I was just able to load 22.04.2 and complete the update.  However, when I boot to recovery and try to run fsck, I get.... /lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory..fsck from util-linux 2.37.2../dev/sdb1 is mounted....e2fsck: cannot continue, aborting

Comment: I got fsck to run form a live cd but get a new error.  This comment area is not large enough for the error so I will start an other...I hope that is correct.

Comment: Comments are from readers to the *Original Poster* or OP.  You don't need to write comments to yourself?  Just edit your question and provide additional detail there... Don't forget this is **not** a forum, but a Question and Answer site, so Answers will be to details you provide in your question (*not from comments which are directed to the OP or prior commentator*)